# An $A$-module $M$ is a module over $\text{End}_A(M)$ if $A$ is commutative

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

From Lang's Algebra:

> Let $A$ be *commutative*. Then $M$ is a module over $\text{End}_A(M)$. If $R$ is a subring of $\text{End}_A(M)$ then $M$ is *a fortiori* a module over $R$. More generally, let $R$ be a ring and let $\rho: R \rightarrow \text{End}_A(M)$ be a ring homomorphism. Then $\rho$ is called a representation of $R$ on $M$. This occurs especially if $A = K$ is a field.

Here, $A$ is a ring, $M$ is an $A$-module, and $\text{End}_A(M)$ is the ring of endomorphisms of $M$.

Why do we require $A$ to be commutative? The results still hold even if $A$ is noncommutative, no? I have let the action of $\text{End}_A(M)$ on $M$, $f \cdot m$ for all $f \in \text{End}_A(M)$ (which are $A$-homomorphisms) and $m \in M$, be defined by $f \cdot m = f(m)$. Clearly this gives a module structure for $M$ over $\text{End}_A(M)$ by the usual laws of addition and composition of homomorphisms, regardless of the commutativity of $A$. What is the issue here?

Comment: There is no reason to require $A$ to be commutative.

Comment: My question is more what multiplication operation do the endomorphism ring use

Comment: The law of multiplication is given by composition of homomorphisms.

Comment: @Qiaochu: So is this just a mistake or did he intend to get to some point requiring the assumption that $A$ is commutative that he forgot about, i.e. is there some meaningful result of letting $A$ be commutative?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I tend to think that Lang requires $A$ to be commutative so that the operation $A\times M\rightarrow M$ given by $a\times m\rightarrow a\cdot m$ is an $A$-linear ($a$ is a fixed element in $A$). This need not to be an $A$-linear when $A$ is not commutative.